# Updating state in ViewModel of one screen after event in the second screen - Jetpack Compose Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am building an application for solving queastionnaires. The application has three screens: `MainMenuView`, `QuestionnaireView` and `SettingsView`. From the MainMenu a user can enter `QuestionnaireView` and `SettingsView`, however they cannot enter `QuestionnaireView` unless the *userId* has not been submitted in the `SettingsView` (I am saving the *userId* in SharedPreferences).

In my `MainMenuViewModel` I created `isUserIdFilled` mutableState which indicates (by checking through `checkUserIdFilled()`) whether the *userId* has been submitted.

```
class MainMenuViewModel constructor(val getUserId: GetUserIdUseCase) : ViewModel() {
    var isUserIdFilled by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    init {
        checkUserIdFilled()
    }

    fun checkUserIdFilled() {
        if (getUserId().isNotEmpty()) {
            isUserIdFilled = true
        }
    }
}
```

In the NavigationHost I am checking whether *userId* has been submitted and navigating to `SettingsView` or `QuestionnaireView`. The *if* on `onQuestionnaireClick` works and navigates to `SettingsView` if the *userId* has not been submitted. However, the `isUserIdFilled` state was not updating (the init in `MainMenuViewModel` is not executed again as the ViewModel is still in the backstack and is not recreated) and I was redirected to `SettingsView` all the time (unless I restarted the app). So I added the call to `checkUserIdFilled()` in the NavHost. However, I don't like this approach as it changes the state from the Composable function.

```
@Composable
fun MyNavHost(navController: NavHostController, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.MainMenu.name,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        composable(Screen.MainMenu.name) {
            val mainMenuViewModel = hiltViewModel<MainMenuViewModel>()

            MainMenuView(
                onQuestionnaireClick = {

                    // Is there a better way to do this and avoid the below call?
                    mainMenuViewModel.checkUserIdFilled()

                    if (mainMenuViewModel.isUserIdFilled)
                        navController.navigate(Screen.Questionnaire.name)
                    else {
                        navController.navigate(Screen.Settings.name)
                    }
                },
                onSettingsClick = { navController.navigate(Screen.Settings.name) },
                mainMenuViewModel = mainMenuViewModel
            )
        }
        composable(Screen.Questionnaire.name) {
            val questionnaireViewModel = hiltViewModel<QuestionnaireViewModel>()
            QuestionnaireView(questionnaireViewModel)
        }
        composable(Screen.Settings.name) {
            val settingsViewModel = hiltViewModel<SettingsViewModel>()
            // userId is submitted and saved to SharedPreferences here
            SettingsView(settingsViewModel::onSubmitUserId, settingsViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? How to update `isUserIdFilled` from the `SettingsViewModel` once the *userId* is submitted in a clean way?